# loading object thats inside of an object into a html table

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, filewalker

so i am trying to make a file manger in node.js and socket.io so every time the walker module detects a file or folder it emits an event to the client that puts it in the table using this large function

```
    socket.on('loadItem', function(type, name, dateCreated, size, itemPath, parentPath, fileExtension){
        if (type == 'dir'){
            var itemPathID = itemPath.split(' ').join('-');
            var parentPathID = parentPath.split(' ').join('-');
            console.log('parent-path ' + parentPathID)
            document.getElementById('main-table').innerHTML += '<tr><td><i class="fas fa-folder folder"></i></td><td  class="pointer"  onclick="openChildrenContainer(\'' + itemPathID+ '/\')">' + name+ '</td><td>' + dateCreated + '</td><td>' + size + ' bytes</td> </tr>'
            document.getElementById('main-content-div').innerHTML += '<div id="'+itemPathID+'" class="folder-children-container hidden"></div>'
            document.getElementById(itemPathID).innerHTML += table
        }
        if(type == "file"){
            if(fileExtension == 'js'){
            var parentPathID = parentPath.split(' ').join('-');
            console.log(parentPathID)
            document.getElementById('main-table').innerHTML += '<tr><td><i class="fab fa-js-square js-file"></i></td><td><a class="pointer" onclick="openEditor(\'' + itemPath+ '\')">' + name + '</a></td><td>' + dateCreated + '</td><td>' + size + ' bytes</td></tr>'

        }else if(fileExtension == "txt"){
            var parentPathID = parentPath.split(' ').join('-');
            console.log(parentPathID)
            document.getElementById('main-table').innerHTML += '<tr><td><i class="fas fa-file-alt txt-file"></i></td><td><a class="pointer" onclick="openEditor(\'' + itemPath+ '\')">' + name + '</a></td><td>' + dateCreated + '</td><td>' + size + ' bytes</td></tr>'
        }else if(fileExtension == "css"){
            var parentPathID = parentPath.split(' ').join('-');
            console.log(parentPathID)
            document.getElementById('main-table').innerHTML += '<tr><td><i class="fab fa-css3-alt css-file"></i></td><td><a class="pointer" onclick="openEditor(\'' + itemPath+ '\')">' + name + '</a></td><td>' + dateCreated + '</td><td>' + size + ' bytes</td></tr>'
            }
            else{
                var parentPathID = parentPath.split(' ').join('-');
            console.log(parentPathID)
            document.getElementById('main-table').innerHTML += '<tr><td><i class="fa fa-file-text file"></i></td><td><a class="pointer" onclick="openEditor(\'' + itemPath+ '\')">' + name + '</a></td><td>' + dateCreated + '</td><td>' + size + ' bytes</td></tr>'
            }
        }


    })
```

but if i have alot of file it will crash the browser sending all of that data individualy through websockets is bad i guess :( so now i construct a object like this on server side

```
         dirItems[itemPath] = {
            item:{
                name:itemName,
                type:'dir',
                birtDate:stat.birthtime,
                itemSize:stat.size,
                itemPath:itemPath,
                parentPath:parentPath,
                itemExtension:'null'

            }
          }
```

and i then send it over to the client page but what my problem is is that i don't know how to put this in my table there isnt like a foreach thing for this i dont think i have tried using this with no su

```
var cols = ['type', 'name', 'date', 'size'];

    for (var i = 0; i < dirItems.item.length; i++) {
    console.log("moo")
$('#main-table').append('<tr></tr>');

for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
    $('#main-table tr:last-child').append('<td>' + dirItems[i][cols[j]] + '</td>');
}
}
```

any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do the `for` loops in ES6. The idea is to have your table as the HTML template and then append the results of the for loop as `<tr></tr>` within the `<tbody>`.

```js
var A = [
          {type:'dinosaur',name:'Rex',date:'1 Jan -00',size:'massive'},
          {type:'dog',name:'Woof',date:'12 Jan 2015',size:'impressive'},
          {type:'parrot',name:'Parry',date:'13 Mar 2018',size:'fistsize'}
          ];
for(animal of A) {
  $('#sometable tbody').append('<tr><td>'+animal.type+'</td><td>'+animal.name+'</td><td>'+animal.date+'</td><td>'+animal.size+'</td></tr>');
}
```

```css
#sometable {
  border:1px solid black;
}
#sometable td {
  padding:0.2em 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="whatever_div">
  <table id="sometable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you fancy the old-school way of doing things, then your `for` statement will look like:

```
for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++) {
  var animal = A[i];
  $('#sometable tbody').append('<tr><td>'+animal.type+'</td><td>'+animal.name+'</td><td>'+animal.date+'</td><td>'+animal.size+'</td></tr>');  
}
```